# Misunderstanding variadic templates and template type deduction

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, template-argument-deduction, type-deduction

I'm compiling with C++17 with code similar to this sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

class Foo {};

template <typename... Args,
  typename ostream_type = ::std::basic_ostream<Args...>,
  typename ostreambuf_iterator_type = ::std::ostreambuf_iterator<Args...>>
ostream_type &operator<<(ostream_type &os, const ::Foo f) {
  // Do ostreambuf_iterator_type stuff with 'f' here...
  return os;
}

int main() {
  ::Foo f;
  ::std::cout << f;

  return 0;
```

}

What I've discovered is template type deduction fails when I apply `Args...` to the template parameter list of both `ostream_type` and `ostreambuf_iterator_type`, but it would be fine if I assigned the `char_type` and the `traits_type` from the `ostream_type`.

```
typename ostreambuf_iterator_type = ::std::ostreambuf_iterator<typename ostream_type::char_type, typename ostream_type::traits_type>>
```

Why is this, when the template parameters to `::std::basic_ostream` and `::std::ostreambuf_iterator` are the same?

Comment: I've since realized I can get away with more deduction in the function body, I don't need to specify the iterator parameters, but this code still begs the question why Args... didn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template argument deduction tries to deduce `ostream_type` from the function argument. In doing so it is not bound by the default argument you provided. Rather the default argument is simply ignored.

`ostream_type` will be deduced to `std::basic_ostream<char>`.

Then there is nothing left depending on `Args` in the function parameters and the parameter pack is deduced to be empty.

The empty `Args` is then expanded into the default argument `ostreambuf_iterator_type = ::std::ostreambuf_iterator<Args...>`, which fails because `std::ostreambuf_iterator` needs at least one template argument.

If you want `Args` to be deduced as the template arguments to the `std::basic_ofstream` passed to your function, you need to constraint template argument deduction in the parameter:

```
template <typename... Args,
  typename ostreambuf_iterator_type = ::std::ostreambuf_iterator<Args...>>
auto &operator<<(::std::basic_ostream<Args...> &os, const Foo f) {
  // Do ostreambuf_iterator_type stuff with 'f' here...
  return os;
}
```

Now the deduction has to deduce `Args` as the template arguments of `os`.